# Mysql Query maximum records in n*2 format

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having table `records` like this

```
---- ---------     ------
 id     name       points
---- ---------     ------
 1      aaaa         88
 2      bbbb         87
 3      cccc         88
 4      dddd         87
 5      eeee         86
 6      ffff         87
 7      gggg         87
 8      hhhh         85
 10     iiii         86
 11     iiii         86
 12     iiii         86
 13     iiii         86
 14     iiii         86
 15     iiii         86
 16     iiii         87
 17     iiii         82
 18     hhhh         85
```

form the table, I want to select the records with the following condition

1. For the first maximum record, Highest Points will be on top. (But only one record). I have two record with the highest point 88, Here the recent one should be displayed (maximum id)
2. From second record onwards, the fields should be retrieved in the format of (n*2). I mean, for the 2nd maximum records I can allow 4 values to be equal (2*2=4). i.e in the table there are several 87s, but I select only recent 4 records (Maximum id). similarly for 3rd maximum, I can allow 3*2=6 records to be same.. and so on..

Currently, I've tried with

```
select * from records group by points order by points desc
```

But it limits to only one same record. Is there any possibilities to use `count` or any other relevant functions in this query based on the need. Hope you help me.

Edit:

The output should be look like,

```
---- ---------     ------
 id     name       points
---- ---------     ------
 3      cccc         88      -- maximum (only one)
 16     iiii         87      |
 6      ffff         87      | -- 2nd maximum (allow 2*2 =4 only)
 7      gggg         87      |
 4      dddd         87      |
 15     iiii         86      |
 14     iiii         86      |
 13     iiii         86      | -- 3rd maximum (allow 3*2 =6 only)
 12     iiii         86      |
 11     iiii         86      |
 10     iiii         86      | and so on for 4th and 5th
 18     hhhh         85
 8      hhhh         85
 17     iiii         82
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I'll provide the output format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*Sample data*/
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(9), `points` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `name`, `points`)
VALUES

    ('1', 'aaaa', '88'),
    ('2', 'bbbb', '87'),
    ('3', 'cccc', '88'),
    ('4', 'dddd', '87'),
    ('5', 'eeee', '86'),
    ('6', 'ffff', '87'),
    ('7', 'gggg', '87'),
    ('8', 'hhhh', '85'),
    ('10', 'iiii', '86'),
    ('11', 'iiii', '86'),
    ('12', 'iiii', '86'),
    ('13', 'iiii', '86'),
    ('14', 'iiii', '86'),
    ('15', 'iiii', '86'),
    ('16', 'iiii', '87'),
    ('17', 'iiii', '82'),
    ('18', 'hhhh', '85')
;
```

---

```
/*Query*/
SELECT id, name, points FROM (
    SELECT
    t.*
    , @n := IF(@prev_points != points, @n + 1, @n) AS n
    , @row := IF(@prev_points != points, 1, @row + 1) AS row
    , @prev_points := points
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @prev_points := null, @n := 1, @row := 0) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY points DESC, id DESC
) sq
WHERE row <= CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN 1 ELSE n * 2 END
;
```

---

```
/*Result*/
| ID | NAME | POINTS |
|----|------|--------|
|  3 | cccc |     88 |
| 16 | iiii |     87 |
|  7 | gggg |     87 |
|  6 | ffff |     87 |
|  4 | dddd |     87 |
| 15 | iiii |     86 |
| 14 | iiii |     86 |
| 13 | iiii |     86 |
| 12 | iiii |     86 |
| 11 | iiii |     86 |
| 10 | iiii |     86 |
| 18 | hhhh |     85 |
|  8 | hhhh |     85 |
| 17 | iiii |     82 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain it please?

Comment: Why is your result different from mine - and from the OP's result !?!

Comment: @Strawberry Mainly because of this line: `WHERE row <= CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN 1 ELSE n * 2 END` and because I read the whole task. Would you remove your downvote now, please? I'll upvote you, because you were first (which I didn't see while I was answering) and your solution really isn't hard to adapt.

Comment: that's not what i meant. your ids are entirely different from mine

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, I see, sqlfiddle made id and points column varchar, not int. Forgot to correct that. Fixed it in my answer now.

Comment: @fancyPants I need an update. Now we are getting the results based on maximum. What I need is, if max record is 100, then it is #1, if 2nd max record is 96, then all records falling in between 86-96 ie (96-10 = 86) will be #2 (n*2 method), so the 3rd maximum should be fallen below 85 (86-1) and then all records falling in between 75-85 ie (85-10 = 75) will be #3 (n*2 method) and so on. Can you please update. I really couldn't understand your code

Comment: this is my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238997/mysql-query-maximum-records-in-n2-format-with-range

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave you (others) to figure out the final part of the problem...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name       VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,points INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1      ,'aaaa',88),
(2      ,'bbbb',87),
(3      ,'cccc',88),
(4      ,'dddd',87),
(5      ,'eeee',86),
(6      ,'ffff',87),
(7      ,'gggg',87),
(8      ,'hhhh',85),
(10     ,'iiii',86),
(11     ,'iiii',86),
(12     ,'iiii',86),
(13     ,'iiii',86),
(14     ,'iiii',86),
(15     ,'iiii',86),
(16     ,'iiii',87),
(17     ,'iiii',82);

SELECT x.id
     , x.name
     , x.points
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , IF(@prev=points,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1)i
            , IF(@prev<>points,@j:=@j+1,@j:=@j)j
            , @prev:=points 
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @i:=0,@j:=0,@prev:='')vars 
        ORDER 
           BY points DESC
            , id DESC
     ) x
 WHERE i <= j*2;

 +----+------+--------+
 | id | name | points |
 +----+------+--------+
 |  3 | cccc |     88 |
 |  1 | aaaa |     88 |
 | 16 | iiii |     87 |
 |  7 | gggg |     87 |
 |  6 | ffff |     87 |
 |  4 | dddd |     87 |
 | 15 | iiii |     86 |
 | 14 | iiii |     86 |
 | 13 | iiii |     86 |
 | 12 | iiii |     86 |
 | 11 | iiii |     86 |
 | 10 | iiii |     86 |
 |  8 | hhhh |     85 |
 | 17 | iiii |     82 |
 +----+------+--------+
```

Comment: thanks, but the 1st maximum record allow only one. only `|   3 | cccc |     88 ` allowed, not `|  1 | aaaa |     88 |`

Comment: Really hats off for your effort, except the first maximum

Comment: Which is why I said what I said... but really, it ain't hard to adapt.

Comment: I need an update. Now we are getting the results based on maximum. What I need is, if max record is 100, then it is #1, if 2nd max record is 96, then all records falling in between 86-96 ie (96-10 = 86) will be #2 (n*2 method), so the 3rd maximum should be fallen below 85 (86-1) and then all records falling in between 75-85 ie (85-10 = 75) will be #3 (n*2 method) and so on. Can you please update. I really couldn't understand your code

Comment: So ask a new question, referencing this one.

Comment: This is my another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238997/mysql-query-maximum-records-in-n2-format-with-range